# How to get Quantile/median values in pydruid

Tags: druid, pydruid

My goal is to query the median value of column `height` in my druid datasource. I was able to use other aggregations like count and count distinct values. Here's my query so far:

```
group = query.groupby(
    datasource=datasource,
    granularity='all',
    intervals='2020-01-01T00:00:00+00:00/2101-01-01T00:00:00+00:00',
    dimensions=[
        "category_a"
    ],
    filter=(Dimension("country") == country_id),
    aggregations={
        'count': longsum('count'),
        'count_distinct_city': aggregators.thetasketch('city'),
    }
)
```

There's a class Quantile under postaggregator.py so I tried using this.

```
class Quantile(Postaggregator):
    def __init__(self, name, probability):
        Postaggregator.__init__(self, None, None, name)
        self.post_aggregator = {
            "type": "quantile",
            "fieldName": name,
            "probability": probability,
        }
```

Here's my attempt at getting the median:

```
post_aggregations={
    'median_value': postaggregator.Quantile(
        'height', 50 
     )
}
```

The error I'm getting here is `'Could not resolve type id \'quantile\' as a subtype of [simple type, class io.druid.query.aggregation.PostAggregator]:`

```
Druid Error: {'error': 'Unknown exception', 'errorMessage': 'Could not resolve type id \'quantile\' as a subtype of [simple type, class io.druid.query.aggregation.PostAggregator]: known type ids = [arithmetic, constant, doubleGreatest, doubleLeast, expression, fieldAccess, finalizingFieldAccess, hyperUniqueCardinality, javascript, longGreatest, longLeast, quantilesDoublesSketchToHistogram, quantilesDoublesSketchToQuantile, quantilesDoublesSketchToQuantiles, quantilesDoublesSketchToString, sketchEstimate, sketchSetOper, thetaSketchEstimate, thetaSketchSetOp] (for POJO property \'postAggregations\')\n at [Source: (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP); line: 1, column: 856] (through reference chain: io.druid.query.groupby.GroupByQuery["postAggregations"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])', 'errorClass': 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException', 'host': None}
```

Comment: Seems like the post aggregator that's being created is incorrect. If you look [here](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/datasketches-quantiles.html#post-aggregators), you can see that the "type" should be set to one of quantilesDoublesSketchToQuantile, quantilesDoublesSketchToQuantiles and the structure of the post aggregator is different. Perhaps pydruid is using an older spec?

Comment: @SergioFerragut thank you, yes it seems that way. Now Im not sure how to go about this. Do you think I should just modify the code of pydruid and use the modified local version in my app?

Comment: it is open source, so I'd say yes, make the change, test it and submit a PR to that project. I'm sure there are other Python users that will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code of pydruid to get this working on our end. I've created new aggregator and postaggregator under `/pydruid/utils`.

aggregator.py

```
def quantilesDoublesSketch(raw_column, k=128):
    return {"type": "quantilesDoublesSketch", "fieldName": raw_column, "k": k}
```

postaggregator.py

```
class QuantilesDoublesSketchToQuantile(Postaggregator):
    def __init__(self, name: str, field_name: str, fraction: float):
        self.post_aggregator = {
            "type": "quantilesDoublesSketchToQuantile",
            "name": name,
            "fraction": fraction,
            "field": {
                "fieldName": field_name,
                "name": field_name,
                "type": "fieldAccess",
            },
        }
```

My first time to create a PR! Hopefully they accept and publish officially.

https://github.com/druid-io/pydruid/pull/287